# Kernel selection for one-class SVM learning

Tags: machine-learning, svm, unsupervised-learning, one-class, random-projection

Has anyone seen compelling research on kernel selection for one-class SVM learning? I've not tracked this work in some time and am wondering if there's new work I've missed, particularly from the random projections world related to data-dependent kernel learning, that might be relevant here.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Linear Kernel or a non-linear kernel like RBF.

You may have a look at the following article as well.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0005117917010118